# How to split the width for multiple imageview equally

Tags: android, xml

I tried to put 4 imageview in a row in xml.

This is how I achieve now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.qianonnphoon.tradeal.traderegister.TradeRegisterActivity">

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="278dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="252dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageOwn1"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageOwn1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageOwn1"
            android:id="@+id/imageOwn2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageOwn2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageOwn2"
            android:id="@+id/imageOwn3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageOwn3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageOwn3"
            android:id="@+id/imageOwn4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageOwn1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/tvOwnItemName"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageOwn1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:id="@+id/tvOwnItemDescription"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Category     "
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:id="@+id/tvCategory"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCategory"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/$"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="$     "
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/$"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Item Trade for Item ?"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed4"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Needed Item Name"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvNeedItemName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Needed Item Description"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvNeedItemDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/needItemDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>


        <Button
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemDescription"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />





    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is my output
[image]

However, this code only split the width into 4 part equally on my phone because I set the layout_width and android:layout_height to 90dp. The shape will gone if I run this on other phone size. Any idea to make it always split into 4 part equally? and the height will always follow the width.

Comment: Instead of `RelativeLayout` use `LinearLayout` with weights.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`.
Then for your `ImageView` add 4 to the `LinearLayout`, make sure all of them have a width of `0dp` and set the weight to 1, `android:layout_weight="1"`.

This will make all 4 Imageviews have equal width on any screen size.

Comment: But I need the height equal to width also. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- [`LinearLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with weights
- [`PercentRelativLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)
- [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) with `GuideLine`s

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `ImageView` with `LinearLayout`

Then set `android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"` in your code of `ImageView` .

Try this .

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="252dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="278dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageOwn1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/imageOwn1"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageOwn2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/imageOwn2"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageOwn3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/imageOwn3"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageOwn4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/imageOwn4"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOwnItemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageOwn1"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Item Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageOwn1"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOwnItemDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:text="Description"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:text="Category     "/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCategory"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:text="Price"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/$"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/$"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="$     "/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:text="Item Trade for Item ?"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNeedItemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Needed Item Name"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNeedItemDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Needed Item Description"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/needItemDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemDescription"
            android:text="Submit"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But I need the height equal to width also. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="278dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="252dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/photos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageOwn1"
                   android:layout_height="90dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_width="90dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageOwn2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageOwn3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:id="@+id/imageOwn4" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photos"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/tvOwnItemName"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photos"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:id="@+id/tvOwnItemDescription"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Category     "
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:id="@+id/tvCategory"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ownItemDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCategory"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/$"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="$     "
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/$"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Item Trade for Item ?"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageNeed1"
                   android:layout_height="90dp"
                   android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                   android:layout_width="90dp"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageNeed3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonItemToItem"
            android:id="@+id/imageNeed4"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Needed Item Name"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvNeedItemName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageNeed1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Needed Item Description"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvNeedItemDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/needItemDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility = "gone"/>


        <Button
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/needItemDescription"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />





    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But I need the height equal to width also. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For Similar Width Please Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout as i show below.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageView 
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:weight="0.25"
                    android:id="@+id/imageOwn1"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:weight="0.25"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:id="@+id/imageOwn2" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:weight="0.25"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:id="@+id/imageOwn3" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:weight="0.25"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:id="@+id/imageOwn4" />

    <LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: But I need the height equal to width also. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use scaleType="centerInside" in every ImageView and LinearLayout with weights